# How to limit a thread's execution time and terminate it if it runs too long?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, terminate

A general case for my question was, how do we detect if a particular function call has been taking too long so that we want to terminate it?

On top of my head I think of using a thread to run that function, and kill the thread if it runs too long, as defined below:

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
  public void run()
  {
    someFunction();
  }
}
```

And say someFunction might be:

```
public void someFunction()
{
  // Unknown code that could take arbitrarily long time. 
}
```

In the code above, `someFunction()` might take no time to finish, or takes forever, so say I want to stop it when it's taking too long.

However, in a Java thread implementation, apparently I can't use a shared variable or any timestamp in the thread so that the thread will have a sense of time, because `someFunction()` funs atomically and such check-against-timestamp code can only go after `someFunction`, thus becoming useless since at the point of the coding being executed, someFunction is already done.

NOTE that I also want to do so with `someFunction()` being agnostic. That is, `someFunction()` shouldn't
be worrying about how much time it runs. It simply shouldn't be aware of it at all.

Can anyone provide some insight in how I can accomplish this functionality?

Comment: Are you talking about deadlock? I dont expect people to code like above. Give us exact scenario.

Comment: @almasshaikh There's nothing about locks. I'm simply asking, if I want to make sure, that one thread won't run for too long, or we will kill it, how should we do that?

Comment: use another scheduled thread that runs post your thread start with thread reference in it and wakes up say after an hour and if it still runs interrupt it (provided your thread responds to interruption).

Comment: That's not a sane way to think about the problem. You write the code the thread runs, so code it to terminate itself. Any time you find yourself having to "reach in" from the outside to make a thread do what it needs to do, that's a clear sign you didn't code it to do what you wanted it to do in the first place.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You are right, and I'm thinking about extreme cases, such as an auto code grader, where you have no control over the to-be-graded code, or anything that heavily depends on things outside the control of the program we write.

Comment: I think the problem you describe is Halting problem which is basicly un solvable check this [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: Sounds like you want to detect a stalled thread (takes more time then you think it should.) I wrote this article on that subject that may be of interest to you: http://coopsoft.com/ar/StalledArticle.html

Comment: @OneZero That's what processes are for. The canonical answer to this question is "With the thread's cooperation, you can terminate it using whatever method its supports. Without the thread's cooperation, any such attempt is doomed to fail. Threads *must* cooperate."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an `ExecutorService` to run the thread. Then I would get back a `Future` and use `get()` with a timeout to cancel it.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); // You only asked for 1 thread
Future<?> future = es.submit( new Mythread() );
try {
    future.get(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // This waits timeout seconds; returns null
} catch(TimeoutException e) {
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

Comment: This would block waiting for the future though

Comment: `future.cancel(true)` will be useless unless the function is written to properly handle (not just catch) InterruptedExceptions and interrupts in general.

Comment: Say there are 2 threads. Say, I want each of the threads individually not to take more than 10s. Say 1st thread takes 10s, 1st future.get() will wait for 10s. Say 2nd thread is still running at this point, a future.get() on 2nd will wait for another 10s and so a totally of 20s. How to avoid this ?